# Parameter Variation in AnyLogic: Data for a specific variation

Tags: anylogic

I am using parameter variation in AnyLogic (in a system dynamics model). I am interested in how one parameter changes with the various iterations. The parameter is binary: 0 when supply of water is greater than demand and 1 when supply is lower than demand. The parameters being varied are a given percentage of decrease in outdoor irrigation, a given percentage of decrease in indoor water-use, and a given percentage of households that have rainwater harvesting systems. Visually, I need a time plot where on the x-axis is time (10,950 days; i.e. 30 years) and the binary on the y-axis. This should essentially show which iteration pushes a 1 further into the future.

I have watched videos and seen how histograms and 2D data are used to visualize the results of the iterations, but this does not show which iteration produced which output specifically. Is there a way to first, visually show the output as I have described above and second, return the data for a specific iteration?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parameter variation experiments have **After Iteration** and **After Simulation run** actions that are executed after each iteration and simulation respectively. Here, it is possible to access the values inside the simulation object after it finished but before it is destroyed. There is also a `getCurrentIteration()` method which can be used to control the parameter variation experiment and retrieve the data.

For more detail please consult [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/parameter-variation.html) and see "SIR Agent Based Calibration" example model in AnyLogic example models library (Help -> Example Models).